# Create NSDate with String time from 1970

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string that its value is time. The time is formmated with "time from 1970". How can I convert this string to a nsdate object?

Comment: Is the time the number of seconds or milliseconds from Midnight 1-Jan-1970?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not understand what you meant by "The time is formatted with 'time from 1970'" But here is how to convert a string formatted long containing the number of seconds since 1970 to a `NSDate` object:

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[longValueString longLongValue]];
```

Sometimes the time coming from the servers are in milliseconds. In that case you need to divide it with 1000.

```
NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[longValueString longLongValue]/1000];
```